# Is it possible to run MacOSX (any version) on a Haswell chipset runing VMware ESXi?

Tags: vmware-esxi

I'd like to setup an ESXi with at least one vm that runs some version of MacOSX.   Is it possible to do this using an Intel Haswell chipset (of course it depends on the VT support of the CPU)?  Or is there no support for that yet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: is it technically possible? Probably.

Longer answer: licensing terms for OSX state that it can only be run on Apple hardware. Mac Minis *are* on the ESXi HCL, and I suspect the upcoming Mac Pro will be as well, so your only license-compliant option is to do that.